# Bottom part of UISwitch is cut off on the device but displays normal on the Simulator

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, switch-statement, uiswitch

The UISwitch on my device:    [Switch Image with the bottom pixels cut off http://gorgando.com/uiswitch.jpg](http://gorgando.com/uiswitch.jpg)

The UISwitch on the simulator:  [Good UISwitch http://gorgando.com/uiswitch-good.png](http://gorgando.com/uiswitch-good.png)

As you can see, the bottom pixels are cut off on the device, but not on the simulator. I have tried just about everything I can think of, but nothing has fixed the problem.

Some of the things I've tried:

- Changing the UISwitch's frame's height
- Changing the UICell's height
- Changing the UICell's contentView's height
- Adding the UISwitch to the UICell rather than the UICell's contentView

Here is the relevant code:
This is in the viewDidLoad of the uiTableViewController:

```
UISwitch *sw =  [[UISwitch alloc] init];
self.contactedSwitch = sw;
[sw release];
self.contactedSwitch = [UISwitch switchWithLeftText:@"YES" andRight:@"NO"];
self.contactedSwitch.center = CGPointMake(230, 22);
self.contactedSwitch.on = [self.contact.contacted boolValue];
```

This is where the switchWithLeftText:andRight method comes from:

```
#import "UISwitch-Extended.h"

#define TAG_OFFSET  900

@implementation UISwitch (tagged)
- (void) spelunkAndTag: (UIView *) aView withCount:(int *) count
{
    for (UIView *subview in [aView subviews])
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            *count += 1;
            [subview setTag:(TAG_OFFSET + *count)];
        }
        else 
            [self spelunkAndTag:subview withCount:count];
    }
}

- (UILabel *) label1 
{ 
    return (UILabel *) [self viewWithTag:TAG_OFFSET + 1]; 
}

- (UILabel *) label2 
{ 
    return (UILabel *) [self viewWithTag:TAG_OFFSET + 2]; 
}

+ (UISwitch *) switchWithLeftText: (NSString *) tag1 andRight: (NSString *) tag2
{
    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 94, 27)];

    int labelCount = 0;
    [switchView spelunkAndTag:switchView withCount:&labelCount];

    if (labelCount == 2)
    {
        [switchView.label1 setText:tag1];
        [switchView.label2 setText:tag2];
    }

    return [switchView autorelease];
}

@end
```

This is where I add the UISwitch to my tableviewcell:

```
[[contactedCell contentView] addSubview:self.contactedSwitch];
```

Thanks so much!

**[Update]** I thought the tableviewcell's might be the problem, so I added these UISwitches to a regular UIView to see how they looked. I have the exact same problem where they look alright in the simulator and the bottom is chopped in the device. So bizarre!

Comment: You cannot change the default size of a UISwitch since it will just ignore your code.  You might try increasing the cell size and moving it away from the edge.  If you look closely, it looks like the top is getting clipped in the simulator and the bottom is getting clipped on the device.  So either way it's getting clipped.

Comment: I just added switches to a regular UIView and got the same result. They look alright in the simulator, but the bottom is still cut off on the device. I guess this eliminates the UITableViewCell not being big enough because these UISwitches have plenty of space around them on all sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never figured out exactly what was wrong, but I ended up creating the UISwitches in IB and got it to work beautifully that way. Very weird that it works in IB and not programmatically when I am basically doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when programatically creating a UISwitch and changing its frame's origin- it turned out to be a half-pixel issue.

A key to noticing half-pixel bugs is: do the unwanted artifacts appear differently on the simulator vs device?

Your solution of placing the UISwitch with Interface Builder fixes this- you can also make sure to floor() your new coordinates if you are setting the UISwitch's frame's origin x/y.

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame(CGRectZero)];
CGRect switchFrame = mySwitch.frame;  
// move frame up without pixel fractions
switchFrame.origin.y = floor((cell.contentView.frame.size.height - switchFrame.size.height) / 2); 
mySwitch.frame = switchFrame;
[cell.contentView addSubview:mySwitch];
```

In the original poster's case, the height of a uiswitch is an odd number (27 pixels), so setting the center to 22 splits the height into 13.5. The UISwitch's origin's y coordinate becomes 22-13.5 = 8.5 pixels. Either don't move a UISwitch by setting its center, or floor the coordinate, or use a fraction in the call to CGPointMake(230,22.5).

Another way to track this type of bug is to grep through Interface Builder looking for ".5" coordinates. I have found that sometimes over-tweaking the placement of UI elements in Interface Builder introduces this bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused of the UISwich's top.
You can use `UISwich.origin.y = ceil((height - UISwich.size.height)/2)`
to fix it.